# Fading a tag in, fading it out and then changing the text before repeating the process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an  tag that is having its contents changed via jquery and then faded in and out (using the velocity js library) utilizing the setInterval function. When I run this it tends to work fine for about 30 seconds before it starts to malfunction and jquery starts to change the contents of the  tag before the tag has faded out.

Here is the Javascript code

```
let counter = 0;

function chooseWord() {
    let words = ["foo", "bar", "foo"];

    if (counter !== 2) {
        counter += 1;
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }

    return words[counter];
}

function refreshText() {
    $("#div").text("Foo " + chooseWord())
        .velocity("fadeIn", {
            duration: 2500
        })
        .velocity("fadeOut", {
            delay: 1500,
            duration: 2500
        });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshText();

    setInterval(function() {
        refreshText();
    }, 7000);
});
```

And here is my tag that is being used

```
<h1 class="foobar" id="div"></h1>
```

I've tried using Jquery's timer and I have the same issue. Does anyone know what the problem might be or maybe a different way of achieving what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the order of operations. I have moved the text-change command after fade-out. So the element fades out, and then jQuery will update its text.

```
$("#div")
.velocity("fadeIn", {
  duration: 2500
})
.velocity("fadeOut", {
  delay: 1500,
  duration: 2500
})
.text("Foo " + chooseWord());
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nisarg0/gLed0h1y/

Comment: After about a minute it starts to change mid animation. Same problem.

Comment: I don't see it for some reason, but I think it might be because the timings are not in sync. If you update the setInterval in document.ready to run at 7500 instead of 7000, it should work fine. The reason being that your entire animation takes 7500 ms.